# Is there a way to identify if an int in an array is single or double digit?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to identify if an `int` in an array is a single or double digit?

For instance, this array: `[2,4,14,77]`

`array[0]` is a single digit, I would get an output would say that it is a single,
whereas `array[2]` is of double digit, so the output would say that it is a double.

How would one go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if the number is greater than 9 or less than -9.

```
for n in numArray {
    if n > 9 || n < -9 {
        println("double")
    } else {
        println("single")
    }
}
```

You could even go as far to add this as an extension to Int to make it more convenient:

```
extension Int {
    func isDouble() -> Bool {
        if self > 9 || self < -9 {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } 
}
```

You could then use it in context like this"

```
for n in numArray {
    var digits = (n.isDouble()) ? "double" : "single"
    println("Number \(n) is \(digits)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about converting Int into a String and then counting characters or compare value with the value of 10, or map your array to the array with 1 or 2 ex

```
let mapped = array.map({(int:Int) -> Int in

    if int < 10{

        return 1
    }else{
        return 2
    }

})

println(mapped[0])

println(mapped[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
var numbers = [2,4,14,77]

for item in numbers {

    let digit = map(item.description) {($0)}.count
    println(digit)
}
```

And result will be:

```
1
1
2
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var arr = [2,4,14,77]

for num in arr {

    if num/10 > 0 {
        println("more than one digit \(num)")
    } else {
        println("one digits \(num)")
    }

}
```